# Jasmine-Tests - Get elements inside <ng-template> (Angular)

Tags: html, angular, testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I would like to test HTML elements within a ng-tamplate.

```
<ng-template>
  <button class="create"></button>
</ng-template>
```

Jasmine Test:

```
fixture = TestBed.createComponent(SomeComponent);
const htmlElement: HTMLElement = fixture.nativeElement;
// Does not work:
const p = htmlElement.querySelector('.create');
```

How can I get the html element inside the ng-template? If I place the button outside of the ng-template tag, it works. I think it has something to do with the shadow dom.

Versions: Jasmine 2.8.0; Angular 5.2.9

Comment: You have to create EmbeddedView.

Comment: Could you please clarify how to create an embeddedView?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I forgot to call `fixture.detectChanges();`. Only when you call this method, the component is rendered fully into the DOM (including shadow-DOM-elements). The following code works:

```
fixture = TestBed.createComponent(SomeComponent);
fixture.detectChanges();
const htmlElement: HTMLElement = fixture.nativeElement;
const p = htmlElement.querySelector('.create');
```

See https://angular.io/guide/testing#detectchanges for more details.

Comment: we tried using fixture.detectChanges but could not get this to work. Is it that simple ? I was reading some other post where they are suggesting to create a wrapper component.

Comment: I have the same issue and this solution didn't work for me.

Comment: that did not work

Comment: it does not work